# How can I purchase a 3 day AB pass on an Opus Card in Montréal, and what are the options for traveling to Longueuil from the airport?

Tags: public-transport, fares, montreal

I am traveling to Montréal and will be staying in Longueuil. I am arriving in the evening. I am planning on purchasing a 3 day unlimited Zones AB pass (`3-day, All Modes AB` on https://www.stm.info/sites/default/files/pdf/en/tarifs.pdf). There is a note here that states:

> To load this fare onto an OPUS card, you must obtain a new card designated for this zone. More information is available at métro station fare booths and metropolitan ticket offices. Subject to applicable fees.

However, the STM's Opus Card page is ambiguous on how to purchase this and I'd like to know in advance since I also plan on purchasing two 747 tickets for the two airport trips and I'm not sure if that requires a card (if it does, I'd like to make sure I have a Zones AB compatible card so that I don't end up with more than one card).

According to https://www.stm.info/en/info/fares/opus-cards-and-other-fare-media/opus-card, for anything beyond the A fare zone, a designated Opus card must be purchased for AB, ABC, and ABCD zones. It only mentions 1, 2, or 10 trip formats here, however and does not note the airport fare or day/month passes. https://www.stm.info/sites/default/files/media/Communications/2022/Tarification/tb_carte_opus_tous_modes_multizones_et_bus_hors_territoire_lieux_emission_eng_r01_2022-09-09.pdf specifically mentions the 1, 2, or 10 trip formats and does not mention either the Airport as a sales point or the multi-day passes.

My questions are therefore as follows:

1. Is the fare for the 747 airport bus functionally equivalent to the All Modes A 24-hour pass? They cost the same amount, and it is stated on https://www.stm.info/en/info/fares/transit-fares/yul-aeroport-centre-ville-747 that the airport fare covers Zone A only.
2. Is it possible to purchase a Zones AB Opus Card at the airport, load it with a 747 pass, and then load it with a 3 day All Modes AB pass in Longueuil the next day, or is that Opus Card not purchasable at the airport?
3. Are there paper ticket equivalents for the 747 pass and 3-day All Modes AB pass? If so, is it even worth what seems to be a major headache trying to get an Opus Card that will work on the entire metro network?
4. If the 747 fare does not cover trips to Longueuil and I need to pay an additional fare when I get on the metro anyways, are there better options for airport to Longueuil?

Note 1: I do NOT plan on riding exo - I just need Metro and REM access (my hotel is in Longueuil)
Note 2: According to https://www.stm.info/en/info/fares/points-sale, it is possible to buy the 3 day All modes AB pass at the airport, but it doesn't specify how the fare is dispensed (Opus/paper/other)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will not be able to obtain a dedicated AB Opus card if you're just buying a 3-day pass: they will tell you to use a paper smart ticket (L’Occasionnelle) instead. The dedicated AB Opus cards are designed for people buying monthly passes or 10-ride bundles. Regardless, you cannot obtain one at the airport anyway.

When you buy a 3-day AB ticket (or other ticket) from a large fare vending machines (including the ones at the airport), it will be issued on L'Occasionnelle (paper smart ticket). You do not require an Opus card.

To answer your specific questions:

1. Yes, the 747 fare is equivalent to a 24h All Modes A pass, unless it is purchased at one of the parking meter-style terminals downtown (in which case it is valid for a one-way journey to the airport only and must be used within two hours of purchase).
2. You cannot purchase an AB Opus card at the airport.
3. It is not worth the headache to get an AB Opus card when you can use L'Occasionnelle paper smart tickets instead.
4. The 747 fare will not cover a trip to zone B. Given that the price difference is only $1.75, I suggest purchasing a 24h zone AB pass at the airport ($12.75) and evaluating the following evening whether an evening pass ($6.00, valid in all zones after 1800), weekend pass ($15.25, valid in all zones 1600 Friday to 0500 Monday), 3-day or 24h passes are the best value for your remaining days and travel pattern. Note that while the 24h passes are valid for 24 continuous hours, 3-day passes are only valid for 3 calendar days.